# How does this type E oscillator work?

Tags: capacitor, oscillator

I recently watched this video (link below) that showed me a simplified circuit diagram for a "type E oscillator". I tried researching this, but I couldn't find much information on this.

Please explain to me how this circuit (shown below) works, specifically how the capacitors Cg and Cd pull down the gate voltage for the mosfet, allow for the oscillating circuit to be self produced (which is how the video described it to work).

[image: schematic]

Source: [YouTube - BackMacSci - perfecting and explaining the plasma toroid](https://youtu.be/GbMAvn7nRWo) ([this timestamp](https://youtu.be/GbMAvn7nRWo?t=892)).

Comment: Something like this https://sbmicro.org.br/sforum-eventos/sforum2012/010.pdf

Comment: Note the different frequencies. This one works at ~10 MHz. The linked note works at 125 kHz ...